# Unable to start KDE on Kubuntu

Tags: boot, kubuntu, kde

Today I started my computer and I sudently had to follow a wizard to set the timezone, the user account and the keyboard layout. It restarted automatically and after that, nothing :/

I have the Kubuntu logo at boot followed by a black screen and the message:

```
starting version 219
```

Any clue? I simply cannot use it !

**Edit**: I tried this command after pressing Ctrl + Alt + F2 when the message is displayed:

```
sudo systemctl enable sddm.service -f
reboot
```

But nothing new happened. Systemd seems pretty buggy as it is not the first time I'm not able to boot after an update. Even the manpage is buggy !

Comment: I found a great soluton: remove Kubuntu.